# Multiple string replacements in a text field

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

I have a table that contains HTML content. This content may contain one or several URLs. I also have a mapping table that contains URLs with their associated rewrite.
I need to be able in each HTML  content to replace all the URLs with their rewrite when it exists.

The use case (Postgres 9.5):

```
TABLE some_content (content_id int4, content text)
row1: 1, 'A BA BLAH PIKA',
row2: 2, 'B AB',
row3: 3, 'C PIKA NOTA CA'

TABLE rewrite (rule_id int4, old_string text, new_string text)
row1: 1, 'PIKA', 'CHU',
row2: 2, 'BLAH', 'POM'
```

The query should ouput the following set:

```
row1: 1, 'A BA POM CHU'
row2: 2, 'B AB'
row3: 3, 'C CHU NOTA CA'
```

Adding a new row in the `rewrite` table like:

```
row3: 3, 'NOTA', 'ISB'
```

would then transform the resulting set into (int4, text):

```
row1: 1, 'A BA POM CHU'
row2: 2, 'B AB'
row3: 3, 'C CHU ISB CA'
```

Any hint?

Comment: Postgres version, table definitions?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter added, thanks

Comment: There should be an ID column in table `rewrite`. On principle and also because the order in which replacements are applied matters. Plus, clarify whether you only want to replace whole words (define delimiters *exactly*) or any match.

Comment: True, added as well. Since the text to be replaced is an URL a whole match is enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each replacement depends on the result of the last. You need a loop of some kind. And you need a deterministic order within replacements. Assuming `rule_id` in ascending order. And assuming you want to replace *any* match, not just whole words (easy to adapt).

You could loop in a plpgsql function. Probably faster. See:

- [Replace looping with a single query for INSERT / UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233369/replace-looping-with-a-single-query-for-insert-update/13238066#13238066)

Or, for pure SQL, try this recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT s.content_id, r.rule_id
        , replace(s.content, r.old_string, r.new_string) AS content
   FROM   some_content s
   CROSS  JOIN (
      SELECT rule_id, old_string, new_string
      FROM   rewrite
      ORDER  BY rule_id  -- order of rows is relevant!
      LIMIT  1
      ) r

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.content_id, r.rule_id
        , replace(c.content, r.old_string, r.new_string) AS content
   FROM   cte c
        , LATERAL (
      SELECT rule_id, old_string, new_string
      FROM   rewrite
      WHERE  rule_id > c.rule_id
      ORDER  BY rule_id  -- order of rows is relevant!
      LIMIT  1
      ) r
   )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (content_id) content
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY content_id, rule_id DESC;
```

The `LATERAL` join to work around `"invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "c"` you would get with a direct subquery referencing the CTE. Related:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Or, using `row_number()` to produces a serial number without gaps [like you commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890170/multiple-string-replacements-in-a-text-field/46890949#comment80729925_46890949):

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
   SELECT old_string, new_string
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY rule_id) AS rn  -- your ORDER BY expression?
   FROM   rewrite
   )
 , cte AS (
   SELECT s.content_id, r.rn
        , replace(s.content, r.old_string, r.new_string) AS content
   FROM   some_content s
   JOIN   r ON r.rn = 1

   UNION ALL
   SELECT s.content_id, r.rn
        , replace(s.content, r.old_string, r.new_string) AS content
   FROM   cte s
   JOIN   r ON r.rn = s.rn + 1
   )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (content_id) content
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY content_id, rn DESC;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d792e2a855a520f92f21bd8154f8caf1)*

It's often overlooked that plain CTEs can still be added after `WITH RECURSIVE`:

- [Multiple CTE in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248217/multiple-cte-in-single-query/35249370#35249370)

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: No worries, I asked for a hint. I went for the recursive CTE as well but found that akward with multiple expressions in a CTE (one for adding the row_number() in rewrite rule to add the asked identifier). Your suggestion to use a loop in a PLPgSQL function is also a good hint. Thank you.

Comment: Now it works. The `LATERAL` join to work around `"invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "c"`

Comment: Is that faster to use `WHERE rule_id > c.rule_id … ORDER BY … LIMIT 1` or to directly `INNER JOIN on an  incrementing id` ?

Comment: @greg: The latter - if you can guarantee there are no gaps.

Comment: Sure, it is obtained through a `row_number()` window function so it should have no gaps. Thank you for the -- as always -- nice and fast reply.

Comment: I added a variant with `row_number()`.